# Naming internal web server

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, domain-name-system

I’ve got server running Apache to serve http files to some Macs for package updates.

Is there any reason not to make the computer name the same as the host name I want to use? I’m guessing as it’s internal only it shouldn’t be an issue?
I will need our sysadmin to set an A or CNAME record for it though correct?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No issue in having all names the same. Simple and convenient, but is not required.

Consider at least two names in DNS:

- Host name for admins, example `web3`. AAAA and/or A record.
- Service name for users, example `macupdates`. Probably CNAME record.

Decoupling these makes moving the service somewhere else easy.

Comment: I’d strongly back the separate host name and service name myself. Make things much easier in the long run.

Comment: So two name records, one IP , dual functions, but either one will resolve to the same server?

Comment: @John Mahowald Your saying A record is the ip to hostname, and the CNAME is second hostname to first hostname?  Thats how I've read it works at least.. Thanks

Comment: Not necessarily. One IP is just an implementation detail, could have multiple, say in a cluster or load balancer.  The essential recommendation is a service name decoupled from a host.